# Oops something bad happen (coming back from linkedin) , Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/import/linkedin

this is the link that was in address bar of browser. I am using google Chrome. It happens when in Careers 2.0 I clicked on linkedin link and it asked me for granting access to linkedin profile. Instead of giving access (as I already have data from linked on careers 2.0) I clicked on browser back button and then I was on this page: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/import/linkedin
that was saying: Oops something bad happen

Comment: Did you click the browser back button or the cancel button on the linkedin form?  I can repro on the cancel button, but not on the back button.

Comment: yes, I think cancel button I didn't remember exactly but I think you are right and yes I clicked cancel button

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Hafiz, this should be good now. Let me know if you experience it again.